# Service Unavailable if I try to access IIS website via IP address, works fine via localhost or 127.0.0.1

Tags: iis

If I try to access the default website in IIS on Windows 7 via localhost, or 127.0.0.1 it all works fine. If I try to access it by browsing to its IP address it fails with the error `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.`

I have the website bindings set to all available IP addresses.

If I set the binding explicitly to its IP address then I can browse to the IP address no problem, however I then cannot browse via localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of IIS - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable

Comment: It was not the same issue, but it lead me to find the solution, thanks. It turns out the `netsh http add urlacl` does not do what another article I had read says it does. That article claimed that that command modified the firewall to allow incoming requests. So I had run that command for the IP address. What actually happens is that it reserves that IP address and port and then IIS cannot attach to that IP address and hence Service Unavailable. I simply deleted that entry and it all works. Now I just need to figure out why I can't see it from another machine.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining your discovery. My problem was slightly different than yours, but the the cause was the same. Thanks alot!